# Algorithm did not converge - Multinomial mixed model (mblogit)

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I'm trying to fit a multinomial mixed model with the mclogit package (using the mblogit function).

But, as I adjusted the model, I'm receiving the following message and I could't find any info about this related to this specific package:

```
Iteration 1 - Deviance = 63629.04
Iteration 2 - Deviance = 60300
Iteration 3 - Deviance = 60032.35
Iteration 4 - Deviance = 60023.69
Iteration 5 - Deviance = 60023.66
Iteration 6 - Deviance = 60023.66
converged

Iteration 1 - Deviance = 58065.79
Iteration 2 - Deviance = 56439.73
Iteration 3 - Deviance = 56349.22
Iteration 4 - Deviance = 56339
Iteration 5 - Deviance = 56336.96
Iteration 6 - Deviance = 56336.49
Iteration 7 - Deviance = 56336.38
Iteration 8 - Deviance = 56336.36
Iteration 9 - Deviance = 56336.34
Iteration 10 - Deviance = 56336.32
Iteration 11 - Deviance = 56336.31
Warning messages:
1: Cannot find an appropriate step size, giving up 
2: Algorithm did not converge.
```

The model gives the results and I'm unaware of problems in the summary, but this message pop up. This is problematic? And what could be the problem with the data set?

This is the coding that I'm using to run the model:

```
mblogit(formula = dropout ~ sex + age_group + 
secondary_school,
random = ~ 1 | institution,
data = stud.db)
```

And this is a head of the dataset:

```
  A tibble: 220,899 x 5
  institution sex   age_group      secondary_school dropout 
        <int> <fct> <fct>          <fct>            <fct>   
 1           1 M     25 to 29 years Public school    Enrolled
 2           1 F     25 to 29 years Public school    Enrolled
 3           1 M     Above 30 years Public school    Enrolled
 4           1 M     Above 30 years Private school   Enrolled
 5           1 F     Above 30 years Public school    Stopout
 6           1 M     Above 30 years Private school   Enrolled
 7           1 F     Above 30 years Private school   Enrolled
 8           1 M     25 to 29 years Private school   Dropout
 9           3 F     25 to 29 years Public school    Enrolled
10           1 M     25 to 29 years Federal school   Enrolled
```

Thanks a lot.

Edit 1:

Changed the variable institution to factor, but have the same problem. I also would like to add unique classes into the random parameter, nested within the institutions (5.110 unique classes in the institutions). Tried like this:

```
mblogit(formula = dropout ~ sex + age_group + 
secondary_school,
random = ~ 1 | institution/class_id,
data = stud.db)
```

Again, it returns the results, but gives the following message and also the variance between institutions and institutions/classes are all inflated and negative.

```
Warning messages:
1: Moment equations give negative variances.
  Your model appears to be misspecified.
  I will use a dummy covariance matrix. 
2: Cannot find an appropriate step size, giving up 
3: Algorithm did not converge.
```

I tried to use a glmer with a simple binary response, and everything works fine. But would be important to specify the type of educational outcome in my analysis.

Comment: Hi, you should provide at least an extract of your data to reproduce your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entered in contact with the author of the package, which replied to me the following message. The package is working fine right now it seems:

`````
the algorithm seems to be broken in the 0.6.1 version. 

This is corrected in the 0.7.1 version which is now available from Github. 

See https://github.com/melff/mclogit/releases/latest 
````
`````